# js arrays help pls

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста задать с клавиатуры 2х-мерный массив 4х4 на Javascript. Кидаю свой код, который делает это 4мя отдельными массивами длинной по 4 каждый.

```js
const n = 4;
var a=[]; var b=[]; var c = []; var d = [];
//var c =[[a],[b]];
var i,j,min,an,bn;
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
  //for (j=0;j<n;j++){
  alert('input a');
 an = +prompt()
 a.push(an)}
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
  //for (j=0;j<n;j++){
  alert('input b');
 bn = +prompt()
 b.push(bn)
  }
  for (i=0;i<n;i++){
  //for (j=0;j<n;j++){
  alert('input c');
 cn = +prompt()
 c.push(cn)
  }
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
  //for (j=0;j<n;j++){
  alert('input d');
 dn = +prompt()
 d.push(an)
  }



 console.log(a  );
 console.log(b  );
 console.log(c  );
 console.log(d  );
```

Comment: "2х-мерный массив 4х4" - это как? О_о

Comment: @Suvitruf cкорее всего 2х значное, в 4 столбика по 4 значений в столбик.

Comment: @Insider почти,это 4 столбика и 4 ряда. Всего должно быть 16 елементов. матрица 4х4 проще говоря

Comment: @YuriyZhulinskiy а в чем вопрос то? У вас клавиатуры нет, чтобы его заполнить?

Answer (score 1):

Пример на чистом js

https://jsfiddle.net/er0L19sj/

```
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    const innerArr = [];

  for (let j = 0; j < deep; j++) {
    let colName = `column - ${i+1}x${j+1}`,
     item = prompt('insert item in' + colName);

    innerArr.push(+item);
  }
  result.push(innerArr);
}
```

Comment: Благодарен,не затруднит обьяснить значение этой  регулярки?let colName = `column - ${i+1}x${j+1}`,

Comment: это не регулярка а лишь красивый вывод сообщения в prompt, код аналогичен  **let colName = 'column - ' + (i+1) + 'x' + (j+1)',**

Comment: Чтож,я очень признателен

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#btnGet").click(function(){
  var matrix = [];
  
  var text = $("#memValues").val();
  var lines = text.split("\n");
  
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var row = [];
    var values = lines[i].split(" ");
    for(var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
      row.push(+values[j]);
    }
    matrix.push(row);
  }
  // check that matrix is rectangular and for NaN-s
  console.log(JSON.stringify(matrix));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea style="width:200px;height:100px;" id="memValues">1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8</textarea>
<br/>
<button type="button" id="btnGet">Get Values</button>
```